# Send selected text to the database

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to send data to my database. The user needs to select a product from a dropdown. By clicking on send the scripts sends this to the database. But when I look at the database I see that the data that is sended is wrong. The script sends the selected ID and not the selected name (text). I want to send the name and  not the id. How can I fix this?

index.php

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Product</label>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM forms";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<select class='form-control select2' id='product1' name='product1' style='width: 100%;'>";
     echo "<option selected disabled hidden value=''></option>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                      echo "<option value='" . $row["id"]. "'>" . $row["name"]. "</option>";
     }                   
echo "</select>";
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

?>  
</div><!-- /.form-group -->
```

send.php

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
?>

<html>
<body>

<table>
<?php
$correct = true;

$product1 = $_POST['product1'] ;

?>
</table>

<?php
if($correct){
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'root', '');

    $query = "INSERT INTO forms2 (product1) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($product1));

            header("Location: ./print.php");  
}else{

    echo "<br /><br />Error<br />\n";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're adding the `id` as the value in your `option` field. If you want to send the name, try `echo "<option value='" . $row["name"]. "'>" `

Comment: I need the `id` for calculations. Is there another way to define the text or send the text to the database

Comment: Sending the id is a much better idea than sending the text for a variety of reasons.  Why would you want to send the name?

Comment: The user can change the `name` in the first table: `forms`. But the name of a posted product in the second table: `forms2` may not change. It need to stay the same

Comment: By design only value attribute value is submitted by the HTML form. If you need id and name both then you can try concatenating them with a delimiter which you think will not appear in the name e.g. If id is 1|xyz or 2+abc where | and + are delimiters

Comment: Look at: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_value.asp In my case the PHP is posting the value to the database. But I want to post the text written in it. I want to post "Volvo XC90" and not "volvo".

Comment: If I delete ID other calculations, that are working right now will not be work anymore.